# Measure of fit when there is little variation in one variable?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I have two models `M1` and `M2` that I use to predict `Utility`. Here's how they look with `Utility` on the x-axis.

`M1`: [image]

`M2`: [image]

Now despite some evidence of clustering, `M1` clearly must be the superior product since it moves well with `Utility` across its range of values while `M2` predicts the same minimum or near-minimum value for over a third of all points, leading to very little variation at low-to-medium values of `Utility`. When running linear best fits, `M1` still has the superior R-squared, but only barely so because `M2`'s is significant just by virtue of fitting a near-horizontal line to capture this non-variability and taking advantage of wildly asymmetrical residuals.

My question is what metric can be used to meaningfully compare the two to demonstrate the usefulness of `M1` and/or penalize `M2` for its asymmetry and basically assigning a uniform predicted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the dependent variable is usually put on the Y axis.

A linear fit with model M2 is completely inappropriate, so comparing R^2 between the two is not a good idea. The relationship with M1 also appears non-linear, although it's not as obvious.

I'd fit a more flexible model (like restricted cubic splines) with both variables and then compare those.

You can also compare the residuals for the two models.

Comment: I am having a hard time detecting any hint of nonlinearity in M1.  The conditional mean of $X$, given $Y$, looks like a linear function of $Y$.  The conditional distributions even look reasonably homoscedastic.  Perhaps the unconventional switching of the axes along with the clustering of data at low values of $Y$ are creating your impression of nonlinearity.

Comment: To me, it looks like there is a curve. The slope looks lower at the lower levels and then appears to be about a 45 degree line.  The odd axes make it odd, for sure. A loess line would help.